# Why I'm not redirected after "Log In"?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

In my `<LogIn />` component I have this.state `redirect: false` and successful auth with `fb` should change it to `true`. After that, I do `<Redirect to='another page'` which doesn't work. After successful `Log in` the route stays on "/login". The difference is only that the `Log In` form is gone.

### `<LogIn />` component:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      redirect: false
    }
  }

  authWithFacebook = () => {
    app.auth().signInWithPopup(facebookProvider)
      .then((result, error) => {
        if (error) {
          this.setState({error: "Unable to sign in with facebook" })
        } else {
          this.setState({redirect: true})
        }
      })
  }
```

Then:

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect === true) {
      return <Redirect to='/expenses'/>
    }
```

### `<LogIn />` is nested to `<App />` and my `<App />` and routes looks like this:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
      loading: true

    }
  }

componentWillMount() {
  this.removeAuthListener = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        authenticated: true,
        loading: false
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        authenticated: false,
        loading: false
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Then:

```
  <div>
    <Header authenticated={this.state.authenticated}/><br/>
    <Switch>
      {
        this.state.authenticated ?
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
            <Redirect to='/expenses'/>
          )} />
          <Route exact path='/expenses' component={ExpensesContainer} />
          <Route exact path='/logout' component={LogOut} />
        </div>
      :
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
            <Redirect to='/login'/>
          )} />
            <Route exact path='/expenses' render={() => (
              <Redirect to='/login'/>
            )} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={LogIn} />
        </div>
      }
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `componentWillReceiveProps` rather than `componentWillMount`?
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Nope. I don't know how to reimplement with `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: could you help me with this?